# Error message when trying to compile scss to css

Tags: sass, gulp, bourbon, node-sass, neat

I'm using Bourbon,Neat,Bitters. Everything seemed good till trying to compile. I tried "gulp" command and Sass commands. I have Ruby,Sass,Nodejs,git installed.  All are very recent. I am getting this error:

```
 ` "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - input"; } Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - input

Backtrace: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:454:in read'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:454:inupdate_stylesheet' C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:215:in block in update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:ineach' C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:294:inwatch' C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/plugin.rb:109:in method_missing'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:360:inwatch_or_update' C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:51:in process_result'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:52:inparse' C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in parse!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/bin/sass:13:in' C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/sass:23:in load'
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/sass:23:in' */ body:before { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; `
```

I think it has to do with the path and the compiler. I've read and tried videos to try to solve it, but no luck. I'm new to this level of complexity. Help would be appreciated since I'm trying to do a project.

Comment: Provide some code without some code, it's hard to find, out the solution. snap of configuration file will be helpful

Comment: tried compiling with third party sass software ??